# How to assign a character using ASCII data?

Tags: c#, char, ascii

How do I store an ASCII character to a "char" literal?

The ASCII character I want to use for my special character is the File Separator symbol:

Decimal: 028
Octal:   034
Hex:     01C
Binary:  00011100

```
// This works in C/C++, but not C#:
static const char FS = 0x1C; // File Separator
```

Comment: Note: there is no such thing as unmanaged C#.

Comment: Chaos: Yes there is: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288474%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: It is still managed. You can just do unsafe things.

Comment: @Chaos: That was just the best way I knew how to explain my situation. Not knowing it was a simple cast, I was thinking there was something funky I had to do to get it to work (like 'char FS = Convert.ToChar(char.GetType(funky-funk#8));') without having to call an 'unsafe' block.  Is there a better word for what I wanted besides 'managed'?

Comment: No, your question was just dealing with the syntactic differences between C++ and C#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would imagine `'\u001C'` would work.

Comment: Changed this to my answer today, because I see that this is the version I actually use. Thanks Marc. BTW: Dig the festive Avatar. I can't seem to get my Gravatar to change. Every time I've tried in the past, my Avatar reverts so some SO Assigned generic.

Answer (score 14):

The static modifier is not necessary and you have to explicitly cast your int to a char.

```
const char FS = (char)0x1C;
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess it was so simple, I didn't even think about the cast.

Answer (score 2):

const char FS = '\x1C';

Comment: The `\x` escape sequence is pure evil - at least for strings. For instance, the difference between "\x9Bad Compiler" and "\x9Good compiler" is pretty hard to spot. Not so bad for a single char though, I guess. I'd still use `\u001c` myself though.

Comment: ChaosPandion got it first. I had tried using '\1C', but that didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: @Jon Skeet:  But you can just as easily use `\x` with four digits as you can `\u` with four digits.  For instance `"\x0009Bad Compiler"` would compile the same as `"\u0009Bad Compiler"`.  And `\x` is more convenient for `char` literals, since you don't *have* to use all four digits.  For strings it can be tricky if you're not careful, as you point out.  But if there's no ambiguity (say there's no alphanumeric after the sequence), then I still prefer `\x`.  By the way, I strongly object to the use of the word **evil** to mean "a tricky or dangerous construct".

Comment: So I'm evil. I jaywalk, I double-dip, I use \x. Mwa-ha-ha!!!

Seriously though, once you run headfirst into this once or twice, you won't ever make the same mistake again. Considering the fun of debugging such an issue, the brain will have a dedicated lobe just for that.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with encodings if you're going to be writing this to a stream; .NET's characters and strings are UTF-16 encoded, so that will actually be written as `001C` (or `1C00`, depending on endianness; I don't remember which). You can avoid this problem by specifying the appropriate encoding when opening the stream.

**Edit:** Actually, this isn't the case! Having just tested it, the default behaviour for `StreamWriter` et al is to use the system's current ANSI code page (usually ISO-8859-1), so it does in fact get written in the expected 8-bit format. This will, of course, give unexpected results for non-ANSI characters.

Comment: @Inquisitor: Would Jon Skeet's and Marc Gravell's suggestion of using '\u001C' prevent UTF-16 streams slips?

Comment: @jp2code: I was actually wrong, so never mind :) However, no, the way in which the character is assigned won't affect how it's written to streams.